# Modules over a Gorenstein ring 

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

$A$ a Gorenstein ring, $M\neq 0$ a finite $A$-module with finite injective dimension. According to Bruns, this implies that $M$ has finite projective dimension. How do I see that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a proof which may not be the best but demonstrates some standard techniques:

Since $R$ has finite inj. dim. one can replace $M$ by a high syzygy, so one can assume $M$ has full depth. Thus one can kill a full regular sequence for both $M$ and $R$ and (as finiteness of proj. or inj. dim are not affected) assume $R$ is Artinian. Now, [your last question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34702/depth-and-dimension) shows that you already know in this case $M$ must be injective.

Map a free module onto $M$ and look at the exact sequence:

$$ 0 \to N \to R^n \to M \to 0$$

As $R$ is Gorenstein, $N$  also has fin. inj. dim., so injective. But then $\text{Ext}_R^1(M,N)=0$, hence the sequence splits, and $M$ must be free.

PS: The name is Bruns. You said in your profile that you are a graduate student interested in commutative algebra. If that is indeed the case, then perhaps taking a serious course  and talking to the experts at your institution would be more effective then learning it on MO (-: Good luck!

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph.

Comment: I was typing too fast: one can conclude the sequence splits from knowing N is injective by definition (-: 

Comment: Are you implying that when $R$ and $M$ have the same depth, there exists a sequence in $R$ that is both $R$-regular and $M$-regular? Or is the projective dimension of $M$ still not affected if I kill, say, a sequence that is $R$-regular but not $M$-regular?

Comment: @kwan: If $M$ has full depth, then a regular element in $R$ is also regular on $M$. 

Comment: Just to make sure: by "full depth" do you mean depth(M)=dim(M) ?

Comment: @kwan: I actually meant depth(M) =depth(R), that why we need to pass to a high syzygy. 

Comment: Could you give me a hint (or reference) for showing the A-regularity and M-regularity coincide when A and M have the same depth?

Comment: @kwan: the set of associated primes of M is a subset of the set of associated primes of R (depth M_p=0 implies depth R_p=0). A R-reg element has to be outside all ass. primes of R, so also outside all ass. primes of M.  

Comment: Sorry, I'm having hard time following almost everything you say. Why does depth(M_p)=0 imply depth(R_p)=0? Are you implying depth(M)=depth(R) localizes?

Comment: No, but if $M$ is maximal Cohen-Macaulay, then $M_p$ also maximal Cohen-Macaulay. 

Comment: @Hailong: Sorry, I can't figure out why maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules localize. Is it a general fact or are you assuming $R$ to be Gorenstein?

Comment: @kwan: If $R$ is CM then maximal CM modules localize. This should be in Bruns-Herzog. 

Comment: @Hailong: I couldn't find it in Bruns-Herzog but I found a nice proof in Eisenbud which also covers A-regularity implying M-regularity. Thanks!
By the way, in your comment when you mentioned Ass(M) is a subset of Ass(A) (Aug 17 5:09), did you mean that the union of primes in Ass(M) is contained in the union of primes in Ass(A)? Your argument doesn't seem to go beyond that.

Comment: @kwan: it follows from the fact that M_p is maximal CM (assuming M is maximal CM). So if depth M_p=0, depth R_p must also be 0. 

Answer (score 1):

I found this proof in Kaplansky's Commutative Rings:

Induction on $\mbox{dim }A$.

$\mbox{dim }A =0 \ $:

Suppose $M\neq 0$. $\mbox{id}(M)=\mbox{depth}(A)=0$ so $M$ is injective, and hence is a direct sum of $\mbox{E}(A/\mathfrak{m})$. Since $A$ is Artin Gorenstein, $\mbox{E}(A/\mathfrak{m})\simeq A$ so $M$ is free.

$\mbox{dim }A \geq 1\ $:

$ 0\leftarrow M\leftarrow A^{n}\leftarrow K\leftarrow 0$

Then $\mbox{id}(K)<\infty$. Since $\mbox{dim }A\geq 1$ there is a non-zero-divisor $a\in A$, which is $K$-regular. Then $\mbox{id} _{A/(a)}(K/aK)\leq\mbox{id} _{A}(K)-1<\infty$ by one of the change of rings formulae. Now $A/(a)$ is Gorenstein and $\mbox{dim }A/(a)<\mbox{dim }A$ so by the induction hybothesis $\mbox{pd} _{A/(a)}(K/aK)<\infty$. By another change of rings formula, $\mbox{pd} _{A}(K)=\mbox{pd} _{A/(a)}(K/aK)<\infty $ so $\mbox{pd} _{A}(M)<\infty$ from the above short exact sequence.

Comment: This is the same proof as Hailong's, with induction replacing the (more straightforward) reduction to the Artinian case.