# Standard reduction to the artinian local case?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Where can I find a clear exposé of the so called "standard reduction to the local artinian (with algebraically closed residue field", a sentence I read everywhere but that is never completely unfold?

---

EDIT: Here, was a badly posed question.

Comment: Your title has "artinian" misspeled.

Comment: Dear Workitout: In order for people to even try giving a reasonable answer, you probably need to be a lot more specific. 

Comment: In particular, could you give an example of the “everywhere” that you read that sentence?

Comment: Read pp. 8--9 in Introduction to EGA I (IHES version) and then Introduction to EGA IV_1 (which is embedded near the end of that volume, after the long Chapter 0).  Then think about Krull intersection theorem and fact that every artin local ring admits a faithfully flat extension which is another artin local ring having whatever desired residue field you want (such as alg. closed) -- this fact (which is also valid for complete local noetherian rings more generally) is EGA 0$_{\rm{III}}$, 10.3.1. That's it. If still unclear and you know someone who can generate EGA-style arguments, ask them. 

Comment: Hailong, this question is formulated in exactly the spirit of how the technique being asked about is generally used, which is to say that almost no information is provided.  The truth is that if someone doesn't know what is being asking about from the little bit that is said, there's no way they'd know the answer (since what is said is exactly what is actually written in papers using this powerful method).  So in that sense, it is a well-formulated question (from the perspective of getting an answer, which is ultimately what Workitout wants, and has now received). 

Comment: Dear Workitout: One other point you should keep in mind is that for a proper scheme over a local ring, the only open set around the special fiber is the entire space. So when you have enough openness theorems at your disposal either for many local properties upstairs (flatness, etc.) or for fibral properties over the base (e.g., relative ampleness of a line bundle on top), it is sufficient to work infinitesimally around the special fiber (once you have exploited finite presentation to reduce to the case of a noetherian base scheme). 

Comment: Dear BCnrd: Indeed, my first thought about the question was the EGA fact about residue field extensions you mentioned. But I think the OP can put more on the question so the answers can be more helpful. Also, there are situations in  my research that I simply can not reduce to the Artinian case (say if you started with something non-Cohen-Macaulay). So that's why I would like to know more about the context of the question.  

Comment: Dear Hailong: The question isn't intended for anything other than situations in relative alg. geom. where one is trying to reduce a general problem to case when *base* scheme is artinian.  Not too relevant to commutative algebra.  Really for thms in relative situation (e.g., flat families of proper curves, relative Picard scheme...). I know exactly what OP has in mind, because it comes up in study of relative problems & deformation theory all the time. The question as written is clear for the purpose of getting an informed answer (which is what OP wants: no obligation to write an essay). 

Comment: Dear BCnrd: I see, I could not get into the OP's head (-:. I have seen that fact used  in commutative algebra (in fact I was reading one paper which used it), although as you pointed out, not very often. In any case, looks like the OP got lucky that you are here on MO.  

Comment: Dear Hailong: there are at least 5 or 6 others here (perhaps more) who are entirely familiar with this kind of reduction argument and so would know the answer too. So no luck necessary. :)

Comment: Dear Workitout, How does localizing at a point in the target preserve the notion of "context", when the conditions include properness and surjective of the map to the base? Maybe I'm confused by your terminology.  Also, $X =$ Spec $A[t]$ is not proper over $S =$ Spec $A$, so how is this an example of a context?  Sorry if I'm just misunderstanding!

Comment: Thank you very much Emerton. I think it is going to help me clarify the situation. I will try to correct the questions as soon as possible.

Comment: Dear Workitout: perhaps you didn't mean to require $X$ to be proper?  Instead "axiomatizing" with this notion of "context", please replace it with a specific thing you are confused about.  I am 99.9999% certain that you are reading Ch. 1 of Katz-Mazur, but anyway, please tell us an actual situation of concern to you (if from K-M, you do not need to review the terminology and can simply tell us one or two proofs that are puzzling you in this respect). Once you understand how that unravels, the general yoga should become clear (modulo perhaps more stuff from the depths of EGA). 

Comment: Let say $D$ is a divisor with possible poles along $Z$. By some computation, I can prove that at the points of $Z$, the divisor $D$ is in fact $\geq0$. Hence it is everywhere $\geq0$.
I hope I will be clearer tomorrow!

Comment: Dear Workitout:  you require $X$ to be finite type, but then say "(or $X = {\rm{Spec}}(A[[t]])$)", yet $A[[t]]$ is *not* of finite type.  So I again request: forget the axiomatics, forget this "context" stuff, just please tell us a specific place in the literature where there is a proof which has you baffled due to the kinds of issues you raise. Once you see how the details are justified in one situation, you'll see how to make it work in others.  There's no point in trying to formulate some kind of "meta-theorem" to cover lots of different geometric situations all at once.

Comment: Dear Workitout, You may also want to look at Brian's answer to this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16292/the-central-role-of-varieties-a-comment-from-mumfords-red-book/ (and also Kevin Buzzard's).  

Comment: I'm trying to prove some claim that (I hope) is not is the litterature. I could try to write it in an other category like an analytic one but for other reasons I'm writting it in the category of schemes. First of all I'm trying to understand the different ingredients needed and how they fit together. Obviously spec(A[[t]]) is not of finite type over A. That perhaps means that I have to feed my text with an other definition of what is an extra data in this kind of context. I'm going to think of it. I'll tell you... 


Comment: Dear Workitout: why isn't it simpler to point us to a *specific* place in the literature where you can't fill in the kind argument which has you confused, we explain that one, and then (as befits your pseudonym) you "work it out" for whatever situation you have in mind?  That would seem a better use of time than trying to fix up your axiomatics above. 

Comment: Is there a way to send a private message to someone on mathoverflow? I don't know what to do with this question. Maybe I should - as BCnrd is asking me - point to Proposition 1.10.1 of Katz-Mazur. I'm not sure to need the technique though it cannot be bad.


Answer (score 29, accepted):

Dear Workitout: The list of comments above is getting unwieldy, so let me post an answer here, now that you have finally identified 1.10.1 in Katz-Mazur as (at least one) source of the question. As I predicted, you'll see that the basic technique to be used adapts to many other settings, and that it is very hard to formulate a "meta-theorem" to cover all cases.  The only sure-fire method I know is to read all of sections 8, 9, 11, 12 in EGA IV$_3$ and sections 17 and 18 in EGA IV$_4$, and then it becomes really routine.  Maybe there's a better method (well I can think of one, but I won't say it here).  I will use the terminology and notation around 1.10.1 from Katz-Mazur without explanation below.

Being a "full set of sections" of $Z/S$ is something which is sufficient to check using the constituents of a single open affine cover of $S$, and also a finite generating set of the coordinate ring of $Z$ over each such open.  Thus, by working Zariski-locally on $S$ we may assume $S = {\rm{Spec}}(R)$ and that both sides of (1) in KM 1.10.1 have $R$-free coordinate rings (when viewed as finite $R$-schemes), and likewise for their sum (as effective Cartier divisors).  Now the assertions (1) and (2) in KM 1.10.1 are identities among finitely many elements of some finite free $R$-modules.  For instance, (1) asserts that certain elements in a finite free $R$-module have vanishing image in a finite free $R$-module quotient.  This is all now a bunch of identities among finitely many elements of $R$.

OK, finally we come to the part with a real idea.  Consider the subring $R_0$ of $R$ generated over $\mathbf{Z}$ generated by those finitely many elements.  It is noetherian.  Now unfortunately your initial algebro-geometric setup over $R$ (the smooth separated finite-type curve $C$, the various effective relative Cartier divisors, etc.) probably does not arise via base change from the exact same setup (including flatness properties!) over $R_0$.  But that doesn't matter:  what would really be swell is if *some* noetherian subring of $R$ which *contains* $R_0$ permits such a descent of the situation.  Now express $R$ as the direct limit of its finitely generated $R_0$-subalgebras (all of which are noetherian).  Does the entire situation descend to one of those?  If it did, we'd be in great shape, since it would then suffice to solve the problem in the case of a noetherian base ring (as that would imply the result over $R$ by suitable base change of the descent from the noetherian subring back up to $R$).

How to implement this strategy of reduction to the noetherian case (after which we'll need to deal with the passage to artin local base with algebraically closed residue field)?  OK, so that's where we are all very fortunate that Grothendieck actually wrote out the entire formalism in total detail to handle basically every such situation one could ever want to handle.  So it becomes kind of a game in finding the references in EGA (which I admit is hard to do if one doesn't know where to look, but is really easy if one has read the right parts). For your particular situation with some smooth separated curves and some relative effective Cartier divisors, etc., the results you need are: EGA IV$_3$ 8.3.4, 8.9.1, 8.10.5 (e.g., (v)), 9.2.6.1, 11.2.6(ii), and IV$_4$ 17.7.9.

I'm not going to say more about how you combine those references here; that is where I again remind you of your pseudonym.

OK, now $R$ is noetherian (even finite type over $\mathbf{Z}$, which is very useful extra stuff to have for other arguments with excellence later in life), and you're trying to prove some finite collection of identities among elements of $R$.  To do that it suffices to check in the local rings of $R$, so you can assume $R$ is local.  Now a pair of elements of a local noetherian ring are equal if and only if they have equal images in each artinian quotient (Krull intersection theorem). So it suffices to prove the general result over arbitrary artin local rings (really just the artinian quotients of finitely generated $\mathbf{Z}$-algebra, so there's no set-theoretic quantification nonsense going on).  Now $R$ is artin local. To check an identity in a ring it suffices to do so in a faithfully flat extension ring. So  finally we haul out EGA 0$_{\rm{III}}$ 10.3.1 to find a faithfully flat artin local extension with an algebraically closed residue field.  That's it!

I presume you can now see why anyone who knows how to fill in such arguments never actually writes them out in papers: it is much simpler to say "by standard limit methods from EGA IV$_3$, sections 8,9, etc." (maybe even to be a bit more specific, as K-M are at the beginning of their 1.8.1), and to trust that the reader will pick up the clue that they should read those parts of EGA if they want to understand what is going in such arguments for themself. It is bad when people don't at least mention the relevance of sections 8, 9, etc., but things could be worse (e.g., Grothendieck could have not written EGA, leaving stuff in a complete mess reference-wise).

Comment: I should stress that it is a terrible idea to do "math via literature search".  If you really want to understand what makes these reduction steps work, learn the *methods* that make them work so you can generate whatever arguments you need on your own (apart from some really subtle things, like Raynaud's amazing descent of flatness in 11.2) without having to go back to the source for each bit. Later in life maybe you'll work with algebraic spaces or who-knows-what, and you then want to easily figure out by yourself how to get what you need in your new setup, etc. This is all just a technique.

Comment: Damn brilliant answer! 

Answer (score 7):

Since I was somewhat critical of the question, I would offer here some reasons why the phrase: "reduction to the artinian local case" may mean quite differently to an algebraist (I was also vaguely aware of the geometric use BCnrd explained, that's  why I asked the OP to clarify).

To prove some statements about a commutative ring $R$, a very often used technique is to pass to the quotient of $R$ by a non-zerodivisor. This is a local analogue of "taking the hyperplane section" in geometry. For examples of  this technique, see the proof of the Auslander-Buchsbaum formula in Bruns-Herzog, or this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34879/modules-over-a-gorenstein-ring/34888#34888).

Now, if the ring you started with is local and Cohen-Macaulay, then after killing enough regular elements you ended up in a local Artinian ring $(A,m,k)$. There are a lot of nice things about such rings: all f.g. modules have finite lengths, the Grothendieck group is $\mathbb Z$, local duality is simple as $A$ is already complete, the representation theory is well-studied, blah blah...

Sometimes you also wish that the residue field $k$ is algebraically closed. This can be obtained by making a faithfully flat extension by the EGA result BCnrd mentioned. Here are a few examples where such extension is useful:

1) The [Auslander-Reiten quiver](http://www.mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/~ringel/lectures/rs/ar-def.htm) is easier to write down (all arrows has trivial valuations).

2) If $A$ is a complete intersection, then one can attach to each pair of $A$-modules $M,N$ a $k$-variety, whose dimension equals to the rate of (polynomial) growth of the lengths of $\text{Ext}^i(M,N)$. This has a non-trivial consequence that $\text{Ext}^i(M,N)$  and $\text{Ext}^i(N,M)$ grow at the same rate! (see [this paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/hy3jg8n2blhggrg9/)).

3) To prove that  there are only [finitely many semi-dualizing](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2734) modules over Cohen-Macaulay algebras, the only known proof is to pass to the Artinian case with alg. closed field and then use relevant results from representation theory.

My hope is although this post did not answer what the OP wanted to ask, perhaps it can be of help to someone who googles "reduction to artinian case" with different motivation and find this MO question.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.